# Getting java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1 while updating record in servlet using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am getting java.sql.SQLException:

> No value specified for parameter 1 error

while updating email address which is 11th column in database.

This is the code:

```
try {
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/authenticate", "root", "root");
                  st = con.createStatement();

                 String query = "update custt set email =? where accno =?";
                  PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

                  ps.executeUpdate();
                  System.out.println("updated");
                 //st.executeUpdate(query);// create a statement
                        ps.setInt(2, acn);
                    ps.setString(11, eml);
                     //eml=rs.getString(11); // set input parameter 1

                     System.out.println("updated value"+acn);
                     System.out.println("updated value"+eml);
                  // acnn = rs.getInt(2);
              /// session.setAttribute("Accno", acnn);
                  //session.setAttribute("C_email", eml);
                // System.out.println("updated");
             } catch (SQLException ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(UpdateDetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }
```

Comment: 1) You're calling `executeUpdate()` *before* setting any parameters, so why are you confused when it says *"No value specified for parameter 1"*? The stacktrace even tells you that the error happens before any of the `setXxx()` calls. --- 2) Even if you move it down until after you set parameters, note that you are setting the values of the `?` parameter markers, not the columns, and the email marker is the *first* marker, aka parameter 1, not parameter 11.

Answer (score 2):

you are executing the statement before you pass the parameters.
This is how it should look like.

```
String query = "update custt set email =? where accno =?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, eml);
ps.setInt(2, acn);
ps.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("updated");
```

The first parameter is always index 1 and the second parameters is index 2, etc regardless of the order of columns in database.

Comment: It would be better if you could explain the changes of `parameterIndex` from (2, 11) to (2, 1)

Comment: within a statement the first parameter is always index 1, the second is 2 etc. This does not matter the order the individual columns are in a database. in this statement you have only 2 parameters, so the first is 1 and the second is 2

Comment: @MartinKariuki Then edit the answer and explain that. It's an imporant part of the answer, and readers shouldn't need to read the comments to get the full answer. --- Also notice that the commenter `Mincong Huang` is not the question author `Hussain Shafi`.

Comment: I have shifted the order as per you suggested and tried below but it is not updating value.